# How to iterate over a boost R-tree?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-geometry, r-tree

I can't seem to find an efficient way to iterate over a [boost R-tree (`boost::geometry::index::rtree`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html). The only method I have come up with so far is to perform a query using a very large bounding box so that a copy of all the elements is returned in a vector, however this is obviously neither space-efficient nor time-efficient. Ideally I'd just like to use an STL-style iterator to iterate over the tree in the usual way, but this doesn't seem to be possible ?

Comment: I guess if you query a large bounding box, e.g., `bounds()` and use the `qbegin()` and `qend()` it will be space- and time-efficient. The tree uses the root node if your box is large. Then, it traverses the tree in linear time.

Comment: Got it - thanks - I had made a bad assumption about `qbegin` and `qend` and I think I see things more clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a query that contains all the element you want to iterate over, you don't have to execute the query to put it all into a vector, but can use [qbegin](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/qbegin_predicates_const___.html) and [qend](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/qend__.html) to iterate over the elements directly. The necessary bounds to catch all elements can be obtained from [bounds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/bounds__.html).

Comment: Aha - thanks - I think I was assuming that I would need to execute the query first to get qbegin and qend but I think I see how to do it now.

Answer (score 9):

**Since 1.59.0**

`begin()` and `end()` member functions are defined in `bgi::rtree`, returning a `const_iterator`. So it's possible to iterate over all elements without the techniques described below. In C++11:

```
for(auto const& v: rtree)
    /* do something with v */
```

**Before 1.59.0**

As others have said to iterate over all elements stored in the rtree you could use query iterator. However there is no need to perform an actual spatial query (pass bounds, etc.). You could pass a dummy UnaryPredicate always returning `true` wrapped with `bgi::satisfies()`. In C++11:

```
std::for_each(rtree.qbegin(bgi::satisfies([](Value const&){ return true; })),
              rtree.qend(),
              [](Value const& v){
                  /* do something with v */
              });
```

Non-iterative queries could also be used for this purpose but it'd require a special output iterator, e.g. `boost::function_output_iterator` implemented in [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator) library (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html). In C++11:

```
rtree.query(bgi::satisfies([](Value const&){ return true; }),
            boost::make_function_output_iterator([](Value const& v){
                /* do something with v */
            }));
```

Side notes:

- The above code requires [Boost.Geometry](http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry) library headers mentioned in the documentation
- `namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index`
- `Value` is a type of objects stored in the `bgi::rtree`
- `boost::function_output_iterator` requires `#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>`
- in C++14 generic lambdas could be used, then the above code would be Value-type agnostic

Comment: Thanks - that looks like a potentially useful optimisation.